# javascript: splitting a string (yet preserving the spaces)

Tags: javascript, regex, split

How do I split a string like this

```
"please     help me "
```

so that I get an array like this:

```
["please     ","help ","me "]
```

In other words,I get an array which preserves the space (or spaces)

Thanks

Comment: @PP I came out with my solution where I do a for-loop and and for each item I check with charAt if it's a space... and that works but I am pretty sure there must be a better way

Comment: Why not create a regular expression and globally match it while capturing? Something like `(\\S+\\s+)` would suffice.

Comment: @PP Can you elaborate the answer if I do "please     help me ".split('\s+\S+') I get an array with one item [the string itself] ?

Comment: Shouldn't the last element be like this if you want spaces preserved: "me "

Comment: @Reimius yes I have corrected it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

something like :

```
var str   = "please     help me ";
var split = str.split(/(\S+\s+)/).filter(function(n) {return n});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQT83/2/)

Comment: @adaneo thanks that works... can you kindly explain what the reg expr does .... regardless I will mark it the right answer

Comment: `\S` matches any character that isn't a whitespace, adding the plus makes it greedy, matching a set of characters, and then `\s` does the opposite, mathing whitespace, and the plus makes it greedy, so it matches a group starting with characters and ending with whitespace, and the next group starts when there is a character after the whitespace etc. The filter removes the match at the end and beginning, and between each group, as those are emtpy.

Comment: I tried from your example in fiddle and it keeps spaces

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio - It's supposed to keep spaces, if you don't want the spaces you'd split and trim each part -> http://jsfiddle.net/sxh8wor7/

Answer (score 0):

this is tricky without using a function;

```
var temp = "", outputArray = [], text = "please     help me ".split("");
for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
    console.log(typeof text[i+1])
    if(text[i] === " " && (text[i+1] !== " " || typeof text[i+1] === "undefined")) {
        outputArray.push(temp+=text[i]);
        temp="";
    } else {
        temp+=text[i];
    }

}
console.log(outputArray);
```

I don't think a simple regex can help this out.
you can use prototype to use it like a native code...

```
String.prototype.splitPreserve = function(seperator) {
    var temp = "", 
        outputArray = [], 
        text = this.split("");
    for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        console.log(typeof text[i+1])
        if(text[i] === seperator && (text[i+1] !== seperator || typeof text[i+1] === "undefined")) {
            outputArray.push(temp+=text[i]);
            temp="";
        } else {
            temp+=text[i];
        }

    }
    return outputArray;
}

console.log("please     help me ".splitPreserve(" "));
```